# How to cd into selected directory to apply code within each dir in a loop (shell)?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh, git-bash

This is what my shell script looks like at the moment

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in ~/Trinchera/shell_example/*; do
    cd $dir
    cd test/inputs/
    ./stepwat -f files.in -o
    wait
done
```

It did run successfully, however it first displayed this error message before actually running.

```
./loop_60_stepwat.sh: line 13: cd: test/inputs/: No such file or directory
./loop_60_stepwat.sh: line 15: ./stepwat: No such file or directory
./loop_60_stepwat.sh: line 11: cd: /home/harley/shell_example/run_60_stepwat.sh: Not a directory
./loop_60_stepwat.sh: line 13: cd: test/inputs/: No such file or directory
./loop_60_stepwat.sh: line 15: ./stepwat: No such file or directory
```

The results are good but I'm wondering what the error means because it still ran the script correctly.

**I want to solve or get rid of this error message when I run the script.** I think the error might have something to do with the `cd $dir` part, because I'm not sure how to properly cd into the selected directory, it just seemed to do the trick for now.

*Btw all the files and folders inside each directory are exactly the same, just the names of the directories are different.

Also I would appreciate any comments or feedback on my format as I am a beginner.

Comment: Some of the directories in `shell_example` don't have `test/inputs` subdirectories. And why do you do it in two steps, instead of `cd "$dir/test/inputs"`?

Comment: before the pair of `cd` commands add `echo "${dir}"`, run the script, then review the directories printed to stdout (by the `echo`) to see if you actually have the desired subdirectories/files; also, do you expect `stepwat` to exist in every `${dir}/test/inputs` subdirectory because that's what `./stepwat` is looking for (ie, a copy of `stepwat` in each subdirectory you `cd` into)

Comment: The second error is because some of the names in `shell_example` are files, not directories, so you can't cd to them.

Comment: Why not `for dir in ~/Trinchera/shell_example/*/test/inputs/`?

Comment: It seems OK here, but you rarely want to continue the loop body if the `cd` fails, as you could run a command in a directory it is not intended to run in. `cd "$dir"/test/inputs || continue` will skip the rest of the body and try the next value of `dir` in the event that `cd` fails.

Comment: Or just `for dir in ...; do cd "$dir"/test/inputs && ./stepwat -f files.in -o; done`. The `wait` command does nothing useful here, because you aren't running any background jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `shell_example` directory contains subdirectories that don't have `test/inputs` subdirectories in them. This causes the first "No such file or directory" error.

The "Not a directory" error is because some of the names matching the wildcard are files, not directories, so you can't `cd` to them.

When these `cd` commands fail, you end up in a directory that doesn't contain `stepwat`, so you get an error trying to run that command.

You can simplify by using a willdcard that matches the final directories that you want to change to. And you can first check if `stepwat` and `files.in` exist before trying to use them.

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in ~/Trinchera/shell_example/*/test/inputs; do
    if [ -x "$dir/stepwat" ] && [ -r "$dir/files.in" ]
    then
        cd "$dir"
        ./stepwat -f files.in -o
    fi
done
```

Comment: Checking introduces a race condition; somebody could remove the directory after the check but before `cd`. Just try the `cd` and check its exit status, e.g., `cd "$dir" && ./stepwat ...`.

Comment: (Which, on second thought, has some of the same race condition, as someone could delete the directory after `cd` succeeds. Either way, I guess the only error would be `./stepwat` not being found.)

Comment: Unless it happens on the first iteration, you'll still be in the previous directory and re-execute that command. Whether it's really necessary to protect against TOCTTOU windows depends on the environment and application.

Comment: It worked great! How would I add a line in the for loop to move said completed folder program to a folder inside the shell_example folder called "complete"?

Comment: `mv "$dir" ~/Trinchera/shell_example/complete`